# GitHubでリポジトリに追加するコラボレーターについて

Tags: git, vscode, github

初心者です。GitとGitHubを今学習中です。
Windows11にVScodeを入れて利用しています。
GitHubにコラボレーターを追加する際はそのコラボレーターの持っている
GitHubのアカウント名を追加するのですか？

Gitをインストールした際に初期設定としてユーザー名やメールアドレス、利用するエディタを指定しています。例えば以下のようなことです。これは自分の端末だとします。自分自身のユーザー名を仮に'teamA'とします。

```
$git config --global user.name 'teamA'
$git config --global user.email 'teamA@・・・co.jp'
$git config --global core.editor 'code --wait'
```

さらに自分のgithubアカウントでログインしたものにgithub_practiceというリポジトリを作成したとします。
ここでコラボレーターとしてteamB-skillupを追加したいと思います。
このteamBは同じteamB-skillupというアカウント名のGitHubを作成しています。

setting → Manage accessタブに移動し、「Add people」を押しteamBと入力するとteamB-skillupのGitHubアカウント名を追加しました。そしてここのGitHubアカウントに追加されているメールアドレスの受信箱より承認しました。

しかし利用するGitHubは、teamAが作成したgithub_pracitceというリポジトリです。別の端末であるteamBのWindows10のVSCodeで
git clone (github_practiceの「code」よりURLを貼り付け)
のコマンドを打つとteamBの端末のターミナルにはgit_practiceがクローンされています。

ここで疑問に思ったのはコラボレーターを追加する際にteamBのGitHubは関係ないように思えます

GitHubとターミナルは何か紐づけでもされているのですか？
上記のようなgitの初期設定でユーザー名やメールアドレス等は設定していますが、
GitHubとgitの初期設定を行ったターミナル(VSCode)の間で紐づけを行った
記憶はありません。

なぜteamＡの端末でGitHub上の「git_pracitce」リポジトリのコラボレーターに追加するのはteamBが利用しているGitHubアカウントなのでしょう？
git_practiceリポジトリになぜteamBのターミナル（VSCode）がアクセス出来るのがわかりかねます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これから先、「プルリクエスト」などが出てきます。そのため１人で２台の端末を操作して学習中です。

内容がごちゃこちゃして分かりづらくなりましたが、言いたいことを理解してくださる方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub から `git clone` したり GitHub へ `git push` したりする際に、必要であればアカウントの認証が行われています。たとえば全く関係ない team_C が `git push` しようとしても GitHub のサーバーに拒否されます。

- git_practive リポジトリが public に公開されているのであれば、`git clone` はコラボレーターに追加したか否かによらず行えます。
- コラボレーターに追加しないと `git push` を行えないようにしているのであれば、各々が `git push` する際に認証が行われます。

  - team_B が GitHub 上のリモートリポジトリへ `git push` する際に GitHub との間で認証を行っており、ここでアカウントの紐付けが確認されています。

GitHub のドキュメントとしてはこのあたりを参考にしてください。

- [個人リポジトリに対するアクセスを管理する](https://docs.github.com/ja/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories)
- [About authentication to GitHub](https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github)